# How to go back one folder in UriKind.Relative Path?

Tags: wpf, path, uri, relative-path

I have this code:

```
imgImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/LivingRoom/chair.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

this gives me:

{pack://application:,,,/ExpressFurnitureSystem;component/ui/Images/LivingRoom/chair.png}

Here i want to delete (ui)  or go one folder up. My requirement is:

{pack://application:,,,/ExpressFurnitureSystem;component/Images/LivingRoom/chair.png}

Because I have all my image files under Image folder not under UI/Image.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the following? (i.e. Adding ../ at the beginning)

```
imgImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Images/LivingRoom/chair.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

I'm not sure if that will do it, but usually two periods allows you to move up one level.

Comment: Wonderful. It did work. I didn't know that ".." would work in string. But it did..Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use `../Images/LivingRoom/chair.png`.

Comment: Wonderful. It did work. I didn't know that ".." would work in string. But it did..Thanks a lot!